# How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)

Tags: jsp, jsf, boolean, el

So we all know that `#{someBean.value}` will try and get the content of some property on `someBean` called `value`. It will look for `getValue()`. However, what if this property is `boolean`? It will look for `isValue()`. What it won't look for is `hasValue()`.

This got me thinking, what exactly does it do?

[Java EE 5 tutorial chapter - Unified Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) refers to `PageContext.FindAttribute()`. `PageContext` sends you to `JSPContext`. None of them actually explain the rules they are following to determine the name of the method they are looking for.

It is also fairly easy to find documentation that says the method names must begin with get. However, I know that `isValue()` works.

Can anyone point me to documentation where this is written down. I'm not looking for tutorials or examples I'm looking for reference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's authoritatively documented in both the [JavaBeans Spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) and [EL Specification.](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/el-3_0-fr-spec/EL3.0.FR.pdf)

To take the `boolean` property as an example, it's described in chapter 8.3.2 of JavaBeans spec:

> ### 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> `public boolean is<PropertyName>()`;
>
> This “is<*PropertyName*>” method may be provided instead of a “get<*PropertyName*>” method,
> or it may be provided in addition to a “get<*PropertyName*>” method.
>
> In either case, if the “is<*PropertyName*>” method is present for a boolean property then we will
> use the “is<*PropertyName*>” method to read the property value.
>
> An example boolean property might be:
>
> ```
>     public boolean isMarsupial();
>     public void setMarsupial(boolean m);
> ```

So, `#{bean.marsupial}` expects exactly the above getter/setter pair.

And in chapter 1.23.5 of EL spec:

> ### 1.23.5 Coerce A to Boolean or boolean
>
> - If `A` is `null` and the target type is not the primitive type `boolean`, return `null`
> - If `A` is `null` or `""`, return `false`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is a `Boolean`, return `A`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is a `String`, and `Boolean.valueOf(A)` does not throw an
>   exception, return it
> - Otherwise, error

#### See also:

- [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not readable on type java.lang.Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952630/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-readable-on-type-java-lan)
- [Java: how to name boolean properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945061/java-how-to-name-boolean-properties/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I had been under the impression that using hasX was valid for a boolean. It is a fairly standard convention but I guess Java(beans) has to draw the line somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Basically what you've stated is all there is to it. EL expects the object to follow regular java bean standards. These 2 should help:

- http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71019