# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException when trying to resolve Boolean properties in EL

Tags: jsf, boolean, naming-conventions, el, propertynotfoundexception

I have the following tree node class:

```
public abstract class DocumentTreeNode extends TreeNodeImpl implements javax.swing.tree.TreeNode
{
    private Boolean isToC;

    ...

    public Boolean isToC()
    {
        return isToC;
    }

    public void setToC(Boolean isToC)
    {
        this.isToC = isToC;
    }

}
```

This is a simple check box indicating whether the document is to be included in whatever or not. However, when trying to reference this from within JSF 2 EL

```
...
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{node.isToC}" />
...
```

I get an exception:

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /main.xhtml @541,64 value="#{node.isToC}": The class 'ChapterTreeNode' does not have the property 'isToC'.

(I think I tried almost every combination, at least I felt this way... ;-) )

How do I resolve that boolean property? What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should not specify the method name, but just the property name. You need to omit the `is` (and `get` and `set`) prefix when specifying bean properties.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{node.toC}" />
```

EL will just automatically use the proper getter/setter for the property (note that this indeed means that the physical presence of the instance variable is not necessary). The exception which you got,

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /main.xhtml @541,64 value="#{node.isToC}": The class 'ChapterTreeNode' does not have the property 'isToC'.

basically means that there's no such method as `isIsToc()` or `getIsToc()` (and it has it right).

Your second problem is that you used `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. You should then really call the method `getToC()` or `getIsToC()` instead of `isToC()`. In the latter case, you can just continue using `#{node.isToC}`.

#### See also:

- [How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236929/how-does-java-expression-language-resolve-attributes-in-jsf-1-2)
- [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example)

Comment: Hmm it's not as easy as it appears. I *want* to call my boolean `isToC` in the class, but the getter's name is supposed to be `isToC()`, too. In JSF XHTML this would be `#{file.toC}`. This now throws another exception: `The class 'de.poyry.pqgenerator.pqtree.ChapterTreeNode' does not have a readable property 'toC'.` I guess I have to give up on naming my booleans the same as the fields?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you used `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. You have to replace it by `boolean` or to rename the getter to `getToC()`.

Comment: Strange stuff! Hmm. So Boolean is just treated as a non-boolean... I decided to rename the getter to `getIdToc` so I can use `#{file.isToC}` from JSF and keep `isToC` as the field name.

Comment: EL does not do autoboxing, no. `Boolean` is an `Object`.