# JSF 2.2 Table conditional rendering not working

Tags: jsf-2.2, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

Im trying to display a simple table with an @Entity infos using the following tag-libs:

```
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
```

Here's the mapped entity attribute, a boolean:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ACTIVE", columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
private boolean active;

//... getters and setters
public boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active= active;
}
```

ps.: by debugging the backing bean, im getting the desired list.

Here's my .xhtml (jsf page) snippet:

```
<ui:repeat var="u" value="#{usersList}">
            <tr>
                <td>#{u.name}</td>
                <td>#{u.login}</td>
                <td>#{u.email}</td>
                <td>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${u.active}">
                            <span style="color: green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <span style="color: red"
                                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
</ui:repeat>
```

Altough the list is not empty, the empty message is being shown, and no row is displayed.

If i force the row displaying, removing the conditional rendering, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 1 of type class java.lang.Long to class java.lang.Boolean
```

for the property **active**.

I've tried a few solutions before asking, like these:

[How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236929/how-does-java-expression-language-resolve-boolean-attributes-in-jsf-1-2)

[javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException when trying to resolve Boolean properties in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437803/resolving-boolean-properties-in-el-not-working)

**Update 1**: reviewing my code, i realised i was *empty* testing an object, not a list, updating my snippet also, so, the conditional on the rows displaying its ok now, but the **active** property issue, still throwing the error.

Comment: It throws the same exception, also tried changing the datatype to String, wich displayed **true**, by using the EL `#{u.active}`, but using `#{u.active == 'true'}` as the condition, doesnt return true, at least, it doesnt throw any error.

Comment: jsf snippet: 
`<td>#{u.active} | #{u.active == 'true'} | <c:if test="${u.active == 'true'}"> active </c:if></td>`

displays:
`true | true | `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JSF tags (e.g. `ui:repeat`) are evaluated in a different (later) phase then JSTL tags (e.g. `c:when`). Therefore the values of your user list are just not available when the `c:when` statement is evaluated. Sometimes this results in a weird behaviour so that it looks like the values are available. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437930/1880810) to get some details.

You should use the rendered attribute of some JSF component:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${u.active}">
     <span style="color: green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <span style="color: red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

turns into:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{u.active}">
  <span style="color: green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not u.active}">
  <span style="color: red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</h:panelGroup>
```

You can also use it for values like this:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{u.active}" value="#{u.name}" />
```

**See also:**

- [c:choose not working in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768798/cchoose-not-working-in-jsf)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Perfect! Thought about using rendered, based on recent studies, but since i havent been using jsf for a long time, im still getting used to new stuff. Thanks for the great answer, and references!