# boolean properties starting with "is" does not work

Tags: jsf-2, boolean, javabeans, el, getter

I have a project that use JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces. I tried to use a simple `<h:outputText>` referencing `#{myBean.matriz}` and I got this error:

```
SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ... value="#{myBean.matriz}": Missing Resource in EL implementation: ???propertyNotReadable???
```

The getter is: `isMatriz()`. Should it be `getMatriz()`?

Comment: Boolean with is-getter works.

Comment: @NazarAnnagurban: wrong. The case matters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `is` prefix works only for `boolean`, not `Boolean`.

You've there apparently *actually* a `Boolean` property.

You've 2 options to fix it:

1. Rename the getter with `get` prefix.
2. Replace `Boolean` by `boolean`. Note that it will default to `false` instead of `null`.

#### See also:

- [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) - chapter 8.3.2
- [How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236929/how-does-java-expression-language-resolve-attributes-in-jsf-1-2/3237160#3237160)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the classpath seems to be a mess as to EL implementation. The message `Missing Resource in EL implementation: ???propertyNotReadable???` indicates that the EL impl wasn't able to find the associated error message in own JAR which should look like this

```
Property 'matriz' not found on type com.example.MyBean
```

Make sure that you don't have arbitrarily downloaded EL JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Get rid of them. The servletcontainer already provides its own.

Comment: I tested with boolean primitive :D