# Boolean Getter and Setter using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering why eclipse produces the following getter and setter if i used the following boolean:

```
boolean isLifeTimeMember
```

[image]

The getter should be isIsLifeTimeMember() and not isLifeTimeMember()

I think it affected calling the variable isLifeTimeMember in JSP. because it will look at JSP  and map it to isIsLifeTimeMember() getter method.

Error will result because there is no isIsLifeTimeMember() method but the getter generated by eclipse is isLifeTimeMember()

Thank you.

Comment: If you're calling it from a JSP, the getter should be `getIsLifeTimeMember()`.  Get is assumed in a JSP.

Comment: Please don't upload image. Just paste the code as it is here.

Comment: I assume you mean that the code is `boolean isLifeTimeMember;` and not `boolean isLifeTimeMember()`. Eclipse does not generate getters and setters for methods!

Comment: @Makoto: The two generated methods should work fine from JSP as well (may be that the EL needs to be `x.lifeMember = true`, though, without the prefix).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eclipse name generation rules are that boolean getters should start with `is`. If the variable name already starts with `is`, then it thinks that no additional prefix is necessary.

Eclipse has a setting that controls the use of `is` for generated boolean getters. Open up Preferences and navigate to `Java > Code Style`. There you can uncheck the option "Use 'is' prefix for getters that return boolean". Eclipse-generated boolean getters will then start with "get", just like all the others.

Java has no problem, by the way, in having a field and a method with the same name.

However, having property names that start with "is" will probably cause problems with jsp. As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945061/java-how-to-name-boolean-properties), it's better to avoid property names that read like questions (isLifeTimeMember) and instead just use the property itself as the property name (lifeTimeMember).

**Code Example:**

```
boolean lifeTimeMember;

public boolean isLifeTimeMember() {
   return lifeTimeMember;
}

public void setLifeTimeMember(boolean lifeTimeMember) {
   this.lifeTimeMember = lifeTimeMember;
}
```

And in JSP if you need to use this variable simply use variable name "lifeTimeMember".

Comment: would it affect my jsp when i call the <s:if test="isLifeTimeMember">

Comment: @newbie - It will probably cause problems. As described in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945061/java-how-to-name-boolean-properties), it's better to avoid jsp property names that read like questions (`isLifeTimeMember`) and instead just use the property itself as the property name (`lifeTimeMember`).

Comment: @MukulGoel - Did you see my comment just above yours?

Comment: Yes i did see that, but your post still reflects the old amswer

Comment: @MukulGoel - no longer. The old answer was not inconsistent with the comment, by the way. But I clarified the point I was trying to make.

Comment: jsp is dead.  is IS back.  Eclipse should update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In case of boolean variable, eclipse prepends `is` to the variable name to form the getter name. I.e. If variable is `boolean present;` then the gemerated getter would be named `isPresent();`

Its not advisable to have an `is` in the variable name.

If the variable name is `ispresent` , on jsp you will lookup by variable name `ispresent` which in turn looks up for its getter, its an boolean so it assumes getter would be `isispresemt();` which was not there as the getter setter generator in eclipse does not add an `is` in case that already existe in variable name.

thus an exception  `could not find the field ispresent` is expected to be thrown

having an `is` in field name , can cause problems, avoid using them