# No Getter Method Error when there is a getter

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am trying to add a checkbox to a jsp to accept terms and conditions before entering the site. I keep getting the same error about not having a getter method even though I do have a getter method and I don't see any typos. I don't understand what I'm missing.

login.jsp

```
<html:checkbox property="termsCheckbox" value="true"/>
```

LoginForm.java

```
public final class LoginForm extends ActionForm
{   
private boolean termsCheckbox = false;

public void setTermsCheckbox(boolean termsCheckbox)
{
    this.termsCheckbox = termsCheckbox;
}

public boolean isTermsCheckbox()
{
    return termsCheckbox;
}
}
```

This is the error I am getting when I go to the JSP:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp 
at line 73

73: <html:checkbox property="termsCheckbox" title="terms" value="true"/>    

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method 
for property termsCheckbox of bean org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN
```

Comment: I don't know what the framework you're using expects, but did you try renaming your method from `isTermsCheckbox` to `getTermsCheckbox`?

Comment: I am using Struts 1. I have another jsp/form with a checkbox set up exactly like this and it works fine. I've even copied the code and just changed the name and get this error on this jsp but no error on the other. I've tried changing the name to getTermsCheckbox and get the same error. I've tried using the auto generate getters/setters method in eclipse to generate them and still get the error. I've tried using a string, I've tried a boolean. Same error every time.

Answer (score 1):

It should be isTermsCheckbox:

```
public boolean isTermsCheckbox(){
    return termsCheckbox;
}
```

And get your property value like:

```
<html:checkbox property="isTermsCheckbox" value="true"/>
```

Comment: That is exactly what it is in his example.

Comment: Normally, its the standard of Java naming convention.

Comment: Yes, but this is a problem with the parser, not the Java conventions. The parser does not (to my knowledge) distinguish valid getters based on return type - they always have to have a specific format.

Comment: Property should be accessed like:
<html:checkbox property="isTermsCheckbox" value="true"/>

Comment: No need to retract it.

Comment: I just tried this, the error just changes to "there is no getter method for isTermsCheckbox"

Answer (score 0):

See the following:

[Java: how to name boolean properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945061/java-how-to-name-boolean-properties)

Write you property statement like this:

```
<html:checkbox property="${form.termsCheckbox}" title="terms" value="true"/>
```

Where `form` is your form LoginForm instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if JSP is this way but there are certain frameworks that require the explicit name get or set prefix for example, setTermsCheckbox and getTermsCheckbox. Try that and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the attribute **`action`** in your `html:form` tag in the file `login.jsp`.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<html:form action="login">
    <html:checkbox property="termsCheckbox">Terms</html:checkbox>
    <html:submit />
</html:form>
```

Next, with the action identified, the associated form **`name`** (*`LoginForm`* in my case) for this action mapping must be the same with the property `termsCheckbox`.

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="LoginForm" type="test.form.LoginForm" />
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/login" type="test.action.LoginAction" name="LoginForm"
        input="/login.jsp" scope="request"></action>
</action-mappings>
```

And the code for the action form does not require anything particular.

```
public final class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

    boolean termsCheckbox;

    public boolean isTermsCheckbox() {
        return termsCheckbox;
    }

    public void setTermsCheckbox(boolean termsCheckbox) {
        this.termsCheckbox = termsCheckbox;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have all of that, I just didn't show all the code in my sample. I should mention that this system has been running for years and it works fine until I add this checkbox to the jsp.

Comment: Perhaps a more detailed stacktrace can display other details.

Answer (score 0):

Its so much late for the answer now and you may already find the solution for this I would like to provide the solution which worked for me.

As you have mentioned that you have **copied** the form, please make ensure 2 things:

1. Your `<html:checkbox property = "" />` tag must be within `<html:form></html:form>` tag
2. Your `<html:form action="">` tag action property should match the `<action path="">` property in struts config file.

During coping the existing code there is a possibility that we may forget to apply changes of 2nd point.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement the following on your form:

```
public boolean getTermsCheckbox()
{
    return termsCheckbox;
}
```